# How can I make a for loop to wait 1 second between each lap?

Tags: java, swing, animation

Well, I'm trying to make a little animation with a for loop and the code is the next one:

```
private class Listen4 implements ActionListener{
    int i ;
    for (i = 0; i<5 ; i++){
            try{
                    if (i == 0){ imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("1.png")); }
                    if (i == 1){ imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.png")); }
                    if (i == 2){ imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("1.png")); }
                    if (i == 3){ imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.png")); }
                    if (i == 4){ imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("1.png")); }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
     }
}
```

The problem is that when I execute the program, the image doesn't change; this has made me think that maybe the Thread isn't stopping each lap.

EDIT: Thanks to all of you!

Comment: The answer is to use the javax.swing.Timer

Comment: And you can switch all the `if`s with `if (i % 2 == 0) ... 1.png... else ... 2.png...`

Answer (score 6):

The problem you've got is that your code is running on the GUI thread, which is what talks to the GUI and renders it to the screen. You call the method to set the icon, but that doesn't actually redraw the screen, it just queues things so that the screen will be redrawn next time the GUI thread gets a spare moment. But then you make the GUI thread sleep for a second, during which time it can't do anything. It won't be able to update anything on the screen until your whole method has finished, by which time you've done all your icon updates and all your sleeping!

The answer is to use a `javax.swing.Timer` to queue up the `setIcon()` calls to happen after a fixed interval. The `Timer` will start a new thread to wait in the background for the right amount of time to elapse, and then it will invoke the `setIcon()` call on the GUI thread. That's the only way you can do it: the waiting has to be in the background, but the GUI update calls have to be on the GUI thread.

Try this:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("1.png"));
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Be aware also that since the `ActionListener` is an inner class, it can't refer to `imglabel` unless it's a `final` field (but that shouldn't be a problem: you can always make it `final`).

For bonus marks, you would ideally not be creating three different `ImageIcon` instances all from `1.png`: you could create just one, and then use it three times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop is running on the Event Dispatch Thread which is responsible for updating the image when you change it. So when you sleep the current, you stop the Event Dispatch Thread which then cannot update the image.

The solution is to create a separate thread to run your loop which sends a message to the Event Dispatch Thread thread to change the image. The simplest way to do this is with a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: You wouldn't write the separate thread yourself, you would use `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Which is why I intentionally left out the details of "creating a separate thread".

Comment: @bcsb1001 Edited for clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionLister al = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    ... // You will have to keep a counter or check the image already in the label 
    //to know which one to switch it to
  }
}
```